# Image.Source using proxy

Tags: wpf, image, url, webproxy

On my WPF page I have, for example, an image (one or more) like this:

```
<Image Source="{Binding Path=PicURL}"/>
```

Also, I have a *Settings* page with an option to switch **ON/OFF** the usage of **Internet Proxy Settings** globally inside my entire *Application*.
If to speak about manual web requests, I can solve it, for example, like this:

```
HttpWebRequest request = ( HttpWebRequest )WebRequest.Create( ... );
if( UseProxy ) request.Proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; 
               else req.Proxy = null;
```

But it doesn`t work on WPF controls like *Image* where content is based on URLs 
and **Internet Proxy Settings** are used.

Is there a way to switch proxy *globally inside entire app* **at run-time**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to modify `WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy`

- [How should I set the default proxy to use default credentials?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299940/how-should-i-set-the-default-proxy-to-use-default-credentials)
- [system.net default proxy c# .Net 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3620232/system-net-default-proxy-c-sharp-net-4)

If those dont work in your situation then a workaround is you can download the "resource" from the Web yourself using WebRequest with/or without the Proxy settings.

You can use that data returned by the web request as a stream to initialise a BitmapImage which you can then set into the Source, or you could save to a temporary file and make the Source point to that local file.

- [WPF Image UriSource and Data Binding using http:\\ URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3148163/wpf-image-urisource-and-data-binding-using-http-url)

You would write and use a "Converter" on your Binding which does the downloading/conversion from image Url to BitmapImage, or maybe a MarkupExtension might be possible depending on your situation.

You'd probably want to use Aynchronous bindings, because the download of the image resource might take a while, and you don't want that to block your main UI thread.

- [Loading image in thread with WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1738978/loading-image-in-thread-with-wpf)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one if you want the proxy settings to be config file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
     <configuration>
          <system.net>
              <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
                <proxy proxyaddress="http://proxyaddress:port" 
                       usesystemdefault="False" 
                       bypassonlocal="True" 
                       autoDetect="False" />
              </defaultProxy>
          </system.net>
</configuration>
```

Cheers